# Getting attributes value declare in xml before inflating

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, material-design

I am creating a custom button `MyButton` extending `MaterialButton`. The use-case is that there are 2 sizes of button *large* and *small*, Large button will be of full width (similar to `match_parent`) and small button will have some `minWidth` lets say 100dp, and most importantly they will have **different padding** and **different text sizes**.
While writing my custom class for `MyButton` how can I check what is the `layout_height` and `layout_width` mentioned in xml so that I can take appropriate action for setting the proper UI ?

I tries getting the view height and width , but they will are coming as 0 coz they not completely laid by that time.
I also tried using `doOnLayout{ }` but this is also not getting called in `MyButton` class.
I also tried a custom attributes for `button_size` and based on that setting the layout params, but also not working.

So ***I am hoping if somehow I can get what are the thing declared in the xml (mainly `layout_width`) so i can update the other property accordingly.***

e.g.

```kotlin
open class MyButton @JvmOverloads constructor(
     context: Context,
     private val attributeSet: AttributeSet? = null,
     private val styleAttribute: Int = com.google.android.material.R.attr.materialButtonStyle) :
    MaterialButton(context, attributeSet, styleAttribute) {
       init{
          attributeSet?.let { parseAttr(it) }
       }

       private fun parseAttr(attr: AttributeSet) {

           if (/* need to check if the declared layout_width is match_parent*/){
                // set some padding and text style
           } else {
                // set some different padding and texy style
           }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the attributes defined in xml for any custom view, we can use the `AttributeSet` getting from the constructor.

This is how I did it.

```
  for (i in 0 until attributeSet.attributeCount) 
  {
    if (attributeSet.getAttributeName(i) == "layout_width" && (attributeSet.getAttributeValue(i) == LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT.toString())) 
    {
      // this indicate that layout_width is set to match_parent
    }
  }
```

In the similar way one can get any attributes and its value defined in xml

Note: in the attributeCount and the list of attribute we are not getting those whose value is setting through data binding

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `addOnGlobalLayoutListener` to do stuff after view is fully rendered:

Define an extension like this:

```
fun View.runOnRendered(onRendered: () -> Unit) {
    viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)

            onRendered()
        }
    })
}
```

In your `MyButton` init method

```
init {
    runOnRendered {
        // Check your view width or height
    }
}
```

--------------------UPDATED--------------------

If you just want to check for `layout_width` or `layout_height` without knowing its exact size, just check the `LayoutParams`

```
if (yourview.layoutParams.height == ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: `addOnGlobalLayoutListener` can be used in fragment or activity in which I am trying to inflate my custom button. what I wanted if I can get the declared `layout_width` of the button in my CustomButton class.

Comment: Do `CustomButton` a view inside your current Activity or Fragment?

Comment: yes. But if I have to update the layout in fragment or activity, it beat the purpose of custom button.

Comment: updated the question, you can refer to that

Comment: I updated the answer. It still needs to listen to the GlobalLayoutListener, there is no way a View knows its exact size before being rendered

Comment: I added an updated section to get the layoutParams, just to check for WRAP_CONTENT or MATCH_PARENT attribute. This doesn't need the view to be rendered before

Answer (score 0):

get `layout_width` value as below

```
val widthValue = attrs!!.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "layout_width");
```

this would return you a string, and convert the string to int (please put your safety checks in place)

```
val width = widthValue.toInt()
```

then

```
if(width == ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT){
    //ToDo "what you want"
}
```